# "For Each Cell" in a Subset of a Named Range?

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

I'm guessing this is an easy one. I want to loop through a named range in VBA, but I want to skip the first cell in the range. Can anyone help?

(PS. I'm a VBA novice, not a trained developer, and teaching myself. This forum has been **very** useful. But if you think I haven't tried to find a solution to this before asking, you are wrong.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way

```
Sub AllButFirst()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRng As Range

    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("namedrange")

    For Each rCell In rRng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rRng.Rows.Count - 1, rRng.Columns.Count).Cells
        rCell.Value = "testing"
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: awesome. exactly what I was hoping for. And I learned something, too. Thanks Dick.

Comment: This will only work for a named range that is a single column. If it's a rectangle or a row, results will be quite different, as opposed to the other two answers that will work in all cases. Not saying the approach is wrong in general, but this particular code needs much more refining.

Comment: Yes, I read more into this question than was there. I think it's a rare scenario where you have a rectangle and only want to skip the first cell rather than the first row, so I assumed that's what the OP wanted. So I answered the question the OP should have asked rather than the one he did. :)

Comment: Oh, and it will also fail if the named range's last cell is on the last row of the worksheet - in that case `Offset(1,0)` raises an exception :)

Answer (score 2):

```
dim i as long, r as range

set r = range("name")
for i = 2 to r.cells.count
  msgbox r.cells(i).value
next
```

Comment: thanks. that'll work. any way to do it with

For each cell in r (and somehow tell it to start on the second cell)
... Next

?

Answer (score 2):

@GSerg nailed this one, but since you had a follow-up question of doing this using `For each`, here's one approach:

```
first = True
For Each c In r.Cells
  If Not first Then
    c.Value = "Testing"
  End If
  first = False
Next
```